# pg_num_rows error

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have a mistake in my code

```
) Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_num_rows() in C:\QG\www\medical-clinic\manip\updateProduit.php on line 49
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0019  386752  {main}( )   ..\updateProduit.php:0
```

I use PHP5 MYSQL
Here is my original code, i don't know why it doesn't word:

```
//VERIFICATION SI PRODUIT EXISTE
$query = "
        SELECT  `panier`.`idProduit`
        FROM `panier`, `produit`
        WHERE `Produit`.`nom` = '$nom'
        AND `panier`.`idPanier` = ".$_SESSION["tempPanierSpec"]."
        AND `produit`.`idProduit` =  AND `panier`.`idProduit` 
        ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numRows = pg_num_rows($result);  //NOMBRE DE ROW (DONNEES) DANS LA REPONSE

//SI N'EXISTE PAS
if($numRows == 0){
    mysql_query("SELECT `produit`.`idProduit` FROM `produit` WHERE `produit`.`nom` = '$nom'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $_SESSION["tempIdProd"] = $row["idProduit"]; }//WHILE
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Panier (idPanier, idProduit, qte)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION["panierSpec"]."', '".$_SESSION["tempIdProd"]."', '$qte')");
}
//SI EXISTE
else{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $_SESSON["tempIdProd"] = $row["idProduit"];}
    $query = "
            UPDATE `panier` 
            SET `panier`.`qte` = `panier`.`qte` + $qte 
            WHERE `panier`.`idPanier` = '".$_SESSION["tempPanierSpec"]."'
            AND `panier`.`idProduit` = ". $_SESSION["tempidProd"];
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_num_rows($result)` -- `pg_num_rows($result)` is only for PostreSQL, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks for that.. i realise it just after. i'll accept your answer in 7 minutes

Comment: Oh i got another error from it : ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\QG\www\medical-clinic\manip\updateProduit.php on line 49
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0016 386840 {main}( ) ..\updateProd

Comment: Your query looks like it is malformed. If it doesn't execute successfully, the query will return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

[pg_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php) is for postgres, to fix this, you can change to [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

*imho, in order to outstanding from other answers*

- your server does not configured/installed with postgres module
- based on your latest comment, if seems that you are passing an invalid SQL

Answer (score 0):

`pg_num_rows` is PostgreSQL function, try using `mysql_num_rows` instead.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`pg_num_rows` is a function which takes a PostgreSQL resource and outputs the number of rows associated with it. It requires the PostgreSQL drivers for PHP, which do not come natively enabled with most simple WAMP installs. Many of them, actually, do not come with Postgre drivers at all.

Your other problem is that you're passing in a MySQL resource to a Postgre function. That won't work. Try `mysql_num_rows`.